# Shops listing (CPT VS Plugin)

Tags: custom-post-types

I need to make a list of shops inside a mall. 
Each shop has several data (hours of attention, facebook, website, images, etc)

I started developing a CPT in a plugin.

The loading of the content works fine, but at the moment of showing it in the frontend, the problems started.

Among the templates for archive, single and category filters, I'm going crazy.

I've already searched for many hours, and I can not find examples.

Can you guide me to a tutorial to follow, or if you know a plugin that does this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Development, but what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the data from your Custom Post Type you can create a post template `single-shop.php` (for example) and place this in your theme folder.

NOTE: The filename must match the name of your CPT - ie `single-{your_post_type}.php`.

Then in this template you can display your data with **the_field()** - eg:

```
<?php the_field('opening_hours'); ?>
```

The plugin you are using for the CPTs / custom fields would probably have help docs that would give you some good examples.

- eg ACF - [Displaying custom field values in your theme](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/)
- eg PODS - [Display field values in php templates](https://pods.io/docs/code/pods/display/)

You may also want to create a template `archive-shop.php` for the listing of all shops (make sure you've set `has_archive ==> true` for this CPT) - if not WordPress will default to the `archive.php` anyway. See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/ for more info on Custom Post Type template hierarchy.

If you want to avoid code there are several plugins that will help you do this, some with point & click options, others with simple [shortcodes]. Off the top of my head I think Beaver Builder + Beaver Themer and/or Elementor + Toolset would achieve what you are looking for.